# How to loop on a variable to might be either a string or a list?

Tags: jinja2

I am using https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/ Jinja live parser. I am expecting the below to print just `allow 30.0.0.0/24`, in one line, following the `else` path.

Template

```
{% if prefixes[1] is defined %}
{%- for p in prefixes -%}
allow {{p}}
{% endfor -%}
{% else %}
allow {{prefixes}}
{% endif %}`

{# I am expecting the below to print just allow 30.0.0.0/24 in one line by taking the else #} 
{% if subnets[1] is defined %} 
{%- for s in subnets -%}
allow {{s}}
{% endfor -%}
{% else %}
allow {{subnets}}
{% endif %}
```

Values

```json
{
    "prefixes": ["10.0.0.0/24", "20.0.0.0/24"],
    "subnets": "30.0.0.0/24"
}
```

Render

```
allow•10.0.0.0/24
allow•20.0.0.0/24


allow•3
allow•0
allow•.
allow•0
allow•.
allow•0
allow•.
allow•0
allow•/
allow•2
allow•4
```

I was expecting to see

```
allow•10.0.0.0/24
allow•20.0.0.0/24

allow•30.0.0.0/24
```

Comment: This is neither an object nor a list, but a dictionary. The odd behaviour your are seeing is because you are looping on a string (which are iterables in Python).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. I came up with this. This is something, but not the final solution.
{% if '/' not in prefixes %}
{% if '/' not in subnets %}

Comment: I also tried {% if prefixes in not string %} {% if subnet in not string %}. It appears better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual test was a good idea, but Python treats string as iterables, which is a great feature of the language, to be honest. So `'abc'[1]`, is a valid statement that would actually give you the first character of the string, in this case, `a`.

One way to overcome this is to normalize your input with an [inline if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression):

```
prefixes if prefixes is not string else [prefixes]
```

This would normalize it to, either the list contained into `prefixes`, or a brand new list of the string contained in `prefixes`.

And then, you can feed this inline if into your loops:

```
{%- for prefix in (prefixes if prefixes is not string else [prefixes]) -%}
  allow {{ prefix }}
{% endfor %}

{% for subnet in (subnets if subnets is not string else [subnets]) -%}
  allow {{ subnet }}
{% endfor %}
```

Wich renders your expected:

```
allow 10.0.0.0/24 
allow 20.0.0.0/24 


allow 30.0.0.0/24
```